# Can't assign 2D-array of function pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have "*This declaration has no storage class or type specifier*" error in Visual Studio than I try to initialize my array with functions.
I'm declare an array in header:

```
typedef void (*MultimethodFunc)(ofstream& out);

extern MultimethodFunc multimethodFunc[][10];
```

In .cpp file I have this:

```
MultimethodFunc multimethodFunc[10][10];
```

And finally I try to initialize it in another .cpp:

```
void TrainTrainOut(ofstream& out) {
    out << "\nTrain and Train" << endl;
}

void MMTrainTrainOut(ofstream& out) {
    return TrainTrainOut(out);
}

multimethodFunc[1][1] = MMTrainTrainOut;
multimethodFunc[1][2] = MMTrainAirplaneOut;
multimethodFunc[2][1] = MMAirplaneTrainOut;
multimethodFunc[2][2] = MMAirplaneAirplaneOut;
```

Another functions just similar to *TrainTrainOut* and *MMTrainTrainOut* with different outs and matching returns. The error is placed in last strings there I try to assign functions to arrray. What I'm doing wrong in this case?
Thank you!

Comment: Those aren't initializations those are assignments.  `MultimethodFunc muntimethodFunc[10][10] = { /* values here */ };` that would be an initialization.

Comment: @Wyck, thanks, changed the title of this question.

Comment: You can't put an assignment at file scope.  Put the assignments in a function and call the function.

Comment: @Wyck, how can I do that? Just make another function and place assignments in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put an assignment at file scope.

The following program gives the error:

> this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*MultimethodFunc)(ofstream& out);

void TrainTrainOut(ofstream& out) {
    out << "\nTrain and Train" << endl;
}

void MMTrainTrainOut(ofstream& out) {
    return TrainTrainOut(out);
}

MultimethodFunc multimethodFunc[10][10];

multimethodFunc[1][1] = MMTrainTrainOut;  /* ERROR HERE */
multimethodFunc[1][2] = MMTrainTrainOut;
multimethodFunc[2][1] = MMTrainTrainOut;
multimethodFunc[2][2] = MMTrainTrainOut;

int main() {

}
```

The following program compiles. It fixes the problem by moving the assignments into an initialization function and calling the initialization function explicitly somewhere (e.g.: main)

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*MultimethodFunc)(ofstream& out);

void TrainTrainOut(ofstream& out) {
    out << "\nTrain and Train" << endl;
}

void MMTrainTrainOut(ofstream& out) {
    return TrainTrainOut(out);
}

MultimethodFunc multimethodFunc[10][10];


void initializeThings() {
    multimethodFunc[1][1] = MMTrainTrainOut;
    multimethodFunc[1][2] = MMTrainTrainOut;
    multimethodFunc[2][1] = MMTrainTrainOut;
    multimethodFunc[2][2] = MMTrainTrainOut;
}

int main() {
    initializeThings();
}
```